# Maximal (permutation) subgroups of $PSL(2,p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, computational-algebra, maximal-subgroup, classical-groups

I have been trying to look at the maximal subgroups of $\mathrm{PSL}(2,p)$ for $p > 2$ prime and believe I have a sufficiently good idea of how those isomorphic to $C_p \rtimes C_{\frac{1}{2}(p-1)}$ and $D_{p+1}$ (using the convention that $|D_{2n}| = 2n$ rather than $4n$) look and interact with others, but I am having some issues with the following:

- I'm not sure how to properly justify that the intersection of two distinct groups isomorphic to $D_{p-1}$ is either cyclic of order $\frac{p-1}{2}$ or consists only of involutions (I think it may only contain one involution or be trivial, but I don't know how to show this much either)
- I have no idea how to go about finding the subgroups that crop up isomorphic to $A_4$, $S_4$ and $A_5$ and I can't try to look at them in GAP to figure it out, since GAP treats $\mathrm{PSL}(2,p)$ as a permutation group and I do not know how to translate this back into matrices.

I have been trying to look at the book on Maximal Subgroups of Low-Dimensional Classical Groups by Bray, Holt and Roney-Dougal but can't seem to find any indication as to what these subgroups actually "look" like.

I have also been trying to look at Aschbacher's classification to attempt to get a better idea of how they work, but the description of $\mathcal{C}_2$ as a stabiliser of a direct sum decomposition has me confused, since I am assuming in this case a subgroup $H$ stabilises a direct sum $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ if $H V_1 \subseteq V_1$ and $H V_2 \subseteq V_2$ but then I am not sure how a dihedral group could do this (in the way I am thinking of them). This also has me similarly confused with the permutation groups since I am not entirely sure what an extraspecial group in an absolutely irreducible representation might be. I know what all of the individual terms mean, but that's about it!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your first question doesn't make much sense because $D_{p-1}$ does not have a cyclic group of order $p-1$ as a subgroup. But note that the intersections of two such subgroups can be $C_2 \times C_2$. I don't really know what you mean by "look like" in your second question.  Elements of the stabilizer of the decomposition $V_1\oplus V_2$ may also map $V_1$ to $V_2$ and $V_2$ to $V_1$.

Comment: Oops - missed the half for that first one, and thank you for the stabiliser definition. I think that makes things clearer.

Comment: I am bad at this website, I didn't know enter submitted comments!
As for what I mean by "look like" I was hoping there would be some common or "nice" way to look at a given representative of the conjugacy class - for example, the $C_p \rtimes C_{\frac{1}{2} (p-1)}$ subgroups are, I believe, all conjugate to the upper (or lower) triangular matrices. I don't know if this really helps though, and I'm sorry if not.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to write down a simple "formula" that works for all primes for the matrices in ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ that map onto one of the subgroups $A_4$, $S_4$ or $A_5$. For example, you can write down $2 \times 2$ matrices generating ${\rm SL}(2,5)$ over various fields, such as ${\mathbb Q}(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is a primitive $5$th root of $1$, but for some primes they will only give it to you as a subgroup of ${\rm SL}(2,p^2)$ rather than ${\rm SL}(2,p)$.

Comment: So there may not be a general way to find out what these subgroups actually are in $\mathrm{PSL}(2,p)$? Is there any way to construct them for the primes where we at least have 5th roots of unity in the field?

Comment: Yes, if a fifth root of unity $z$ is in the field, then they are generated by $\left(\begin{array}{cc}-z^3-z^2-1&z^3-z^2\\z^3-z^2&z^3+z^2+1\end{array}\right)$ and $\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-z\\-z^3-z^2-z-1&-1\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you! That's very useful. I'll try to work through it more thoroughly in the morning.